# React script cannot find "fs" when using Electron to read from a file, how to read a local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I am building this simple desktop app which counts money in a cash register. I am using react, node, and electron to build the app using web frameworks but as a desktop app. I am at the stage where I want to record the history of cash counts and a few other things (Likes sales, etc). I don't want to use a database, but rather just have json files with the days information in it.

My issue is with reading (And probably writing) a file local to the system through electron. I have tried a few different ways but right now I am attempting to use the main electron script to read it in (Since it uses node) and then pass the information to the react script. However, I keep getting issues with the dependencies, particularly **fs** and **path**. Here is the error I am getting from the console.

```
> moneymate@0.1.0 start
> concurrently "cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start" "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron ." "yarn webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js"        

yarn run v1.22.19
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ C:\Users\abeel\Documents\Projects\moneymate\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
[2] [webpack-cli] For using 'serve' command you need to install: 'webpack-dev-server' package.
[2] [webpack-cli] Would you like to install 'webpack-dev-server' package? (That will run 'npm install -D webpack-dev-server') (Y/n) (node:12836) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[0] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[0] (node:12836) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
[0] Starting the development server...
[0]
[0] Failed to compile.
[0]
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\<directory>\Projects\moneymate\node_modules\electron'
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\<directory>\Projects\moneymate\node_modules\electron'
[0]
[0] webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I have installed webpack-dev-server, but running the code still yields this result. I am still very, very new to webpack.

electron.js (Main process)

```
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
const fs = require('fs');

let mainWindow;
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 680, icon: path.join(__dirname, 'logo512.png'),title: "MoneyMate",  autoHideMenuBar: true });
  mainWindow.setTitle('MoneyMate')

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
  readLocalFile()
}

function readLocalFile() {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, './history/April-5-2023.json')
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    mainWindow.webContents.send('local-file-read', data)
  })
}


app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});
app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

App.js (Where the call to get the file information is)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import OpenPage from "./pages/Open";
import TransactionsPage from "./pages/Transactions";
import ClosePage from "./pages/Close";
import SettingsPage from "./pages/Settings";
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

function App() {
  const [localFileData, setLocalFileData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on('local-file-read', (event, data) => {
      setLocalFileData(data)
    });
    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener('local-file-read', () => {});
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(localFileData);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/open" element={<OpenPage />} />
        <Route path="/transactions" element={<TransactionsPage />} />
        <Route path="/close" element={<ClosePage />} />
        <Route path="/settings" element={<SettingsPage />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<OpenPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'electron-main',
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "moneymate",
  "productName": "MoneyMate",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "build": {
    "appId": "<com.your_app>"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-store": "^8.1.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11",
    "nedb-promises": "^6.2.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder",
    "release": "yarn react-build && electron-builder --publish=always",
    "build": "yarn react-build && yarn electron-build && webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\" \"yarn webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js\" "
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.5.1",
    "electron": "^15.3.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.1",
    "electron-webpack-quick-start": "^0.0.7",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.2"
  }
}
```

And lastly, if you need to know the project structure
[image: Project Structure]

Any help or guidance is welcome! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Why do you have `path` and `fs` in your dependencies? It's native nodeJS.